# express-jwt: quickly reject JWT missing essential property

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

I am using express-jwt to create middleware, `jwtCheckMiddleware`:

```
function getTokenFromRequest(req) {
 ...
 throw Boom.badRequest("JWT missing")
}

async function isNotRevokedCallback(req, payload, done) {
 ...
}

const jwtCheckMiddleware = expressJwt({
  secret: ....,
  credentialsRequired: true,
  isRevoked: isNotRevokedCallback,
  getToken: getTokenFromRequest
})
```

At one point in development, the JWTs issued lacked a JTI property.  Newly issued tokens hold the JTI property.

A request lacking a JWT is quickly rejected; `getTokenFromRequest` throws an error.  This works great.

A request with an old JWT -- lacking the JTI -- just times out.

There is a null-check inside `isNotRevokedCallback` on the JTI; I throw an error when the JTI is undefined.  Could it be that the `expressJwt` middleware constructor is not catching this error properly, leading to timeout?

`isNotRevokedCallback` is loosely based on https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#revoked-tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the `isRevoked` function callback should have a signature of `function(req, payload, done)`. The argument passed as `done` is in turn a function with a signature `function(err, revoked)` that should be invoked once the check to see if the token is revoked or not is complete.

If the JWT in question does not have a `jti` claim and you need to trigger an error then **you should be calling `done(new YourError())` to signal that an error occurred**.

You did not include your actual implementation so it's impossible to say for sure that this is the cause, however, it does seem a good candidate.

Comment: Thanks!  The `done` callback was the critical point.  The success case is `done(null, false)` and the failure case is `done(Boom.wrap(err))`, for an error caught in the `isNotRevokedCallback`.